# SQL Server variable return datatype (function)

Tags: sql-server, function

Is it possible to create a function in SQL Server which returns different data types back (depending on the variable you got)?

I have searched the web and msdn, but did not found anything useful.

Comment: can you be more specific on your requirements with sample data?

Comment: You mean like `COALESCE` does? No. not for scalar UDFs. You can use `SQL_VARIANT` or have different functions per datatype. Or maybe rewriting as an inline TVF could work dependant on what the function does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL_VARIANT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829(v=sql.90).aspx

I included link for SQL 2005, but it should be the same for upper versions too.

Comment: I did not try it, but it sounds good and I will try it soon. Thank you